# Which license I should use for public project?

Tags: gpl, mit, license-recommendation, lgpl

#### the brief

I want to do "open source" project.

In my mind, I would like to :

- that the code has always the same license even if it is redistributed or sold etc...
- that the authors and contributors are cited even if it is redistributed or sold etc...

I have been browsing [this site](https://choosealicense.com/) to think about what license to use in my projects.

Historically, I did all my code under the MIT license. While browsing the site, I saw the "GNU GPLv3" license and the internet variant "GNU AGPLv3". I also saw the "Mozilla Public License 2.0" license, which just seems to add a trademark rule.

I read that the GPL3 license requires that any modification have documentation.
I found this rule pretty useful, especially for future pullrequest or contributions.

I also read that the GPL3 and AGPL3 license requires that the source code should be distributed to the user.

#### the project

Right now I'm working on a plugin for KDE plasma desktop environment.

And in this situation, I use [their (Plasma KDE)](https://develop.kde.org/) library and package and [Qt/QtQuick](https://www.qt.io/) library and package, in the form of import, like `import QtQuick.Controls 2.15` or `import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid 2.0` and I distribute my code via [github](https://github.com/bouteillerAlan) and [pling](https://www.pling.com/) (par of [opendesktop.org](https://opendesktop.org)).

#### the question

- Is the AGPL3 license good for my project?
- Under the GPL3/AGPL3 license, is the fact of putting my code on GitHub in public enough to fill the request of distribution of the source code?
- Do I have to give the licenses of the used packages somewhere (Qt, QtQuick, plasma)?
- What happens if someone wants to contribute to my project? Do I have anything to do if they do (an obligation)?

Comment: AGPL is normally meant for interactive apps that run on the Web (the license actually says "network server", though). Is your "plugin" intended to run on the Web or over a network? The way I understand it, a KDE plasma desktop app normally runs on in a Desktop environment, so it's not usually a Web application or "running over" a network as I understand it.

Comment: Yes it is not executed on the web, it is loaded in the desktop environment, but it performs operations via the network (checking for available updates for example)

Comment: GPL is a very popular one. AGPL is usually only used if there is a reason to use it, but you can also use AGPL "just because", if you like - when the program is used on the desktop there's no big difference. IMO it wouldn't be terrible if all GPL software was actually AGPL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU GPL v3 is best for your case.

AGPL is often used for backend applications, databases, and other similar server-side software.

Qt is licensed mainly under the LGPL; some parts are under the GPL (you can check [here)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmodules.html#gpl-licensed-addons)

I'm not familiar with KDE licensing (I know they use LGPL, GPL, and other similar licenses), but it should be compatible.

**This is not legal advice.**